# How to load an in-memory image on a WinForms WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, filestream, in-memory

I'm developing a .NET 3.5 WinForms project in C# and I would like opinions on the best method to render an image in a **WebBrowser** control, directly from an **in-memory** source?
By in-memory, I mean that I have a collection of images that are in a **Base64** encoded string format and I wish to render them on an embedded page in a WebBrowser control.

I had hoped to use the embedded [Data URI](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/embedding-images-in-html-using-c/) option example however this approach is [limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support) to images < 32KB.

I'm hoping that it is possible to convert it to a `System.Drawing.Image` instance and somehow reference this image in a the `src` html tag like so: `<img src="<insert reference here?>" </img>`. Is such a technique possible?

If it's not possible to do this, then I wonder on the feasibility of creating the file in the windows temporary directory and reference from there?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to set up a web server and to load the image via the localhost `<img src='http://localhost/img.jpg'>`.  This prevents creating temporary images images on disk.

If you don't want to deal with a web server, simple image tiling combined with the mentioned data URI parameter would work. A single tile can be obtained by:

```
Rectangle region = new Rectangle(x, y, tileWidth, tileHeight);
Bitmap tile = sourceBitmap.Clone(region, sourceBitmap.Clone.PixelFormat);
```

You just repeat the tile generation for varying parameters of `Rectangle region` until you have covered the complete source image. You might try out which `tileWidth` and `tileHeight` are appropriate to result in tiles with data size lower than 32kB.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however my application is deployable to 3rd party clients and it's simply not an option to create a WebServer. Could you please elaborate on the image tiling approach - sounds interesting?